# How to resolve the issue "unused expression, expected an assignment or function call"?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have tried to import the json file in my react application(App.tsx).

```
App.tsx

import * as currencies from './currencies.json';
```

My Json file will look like below structure:

```
{
  "main": {
     "numbers": {
        "currencies": {
         }
      }
   }
}
```

While running the application, it throws the below error

**(1,1): unused expression, expected an assignment or function call**

After further analysis, i have added the typings.d.ts file within **src**  folder

```
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

But still we are facing the same issue. Can anyone please suggest how to resolve this?

Comment: import currencies from './currencies.json';

Comment: @ma_dev_15: I have tried but not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have resolved the same issue by include the below code block in tslint.json file

```
"linterOptions": {
  "exclude": [
    "*.json",
    "**/*.json"
  ]
}
```